# Unable to set a URL as Default value in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, default-constraint

I am using phpMYAdmin to set a URL as a Default Value to a Field of a Table in MySQL database, but of no luck.

The URL is like this one:

> http://www.kaboodle.com/hi/img/c/0/0/b2/9/AAAADMEBXEUAAAAAALKWPw.jpg

Here is the Table field structure:

```
{varchar(255), utf8_general_ci, Not Null}
```

Comment: No luck... What do you mean? Any error printed by PMA, or some useful info we could use to answer?

Comment: @Macmade. The default value I had set did not apply to the records in the Table. That's what I wanted to ask in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what is wrong, but this will [create a DEFAULT constraint for an existing table using an ALTER TABLE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) to to set the URL value if one is not provided when a record is inserted:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table 
ALTER the_column SET DEFAULT 'http://www.kaboodle.com/hi/img/c/0/0/b2/9/AAAADMEBXEUAAAAAALKWPw.jpg'
```